# Can we check if the object is nil or not, before going to release in dealloc method of a class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Can we check the object is nil or not before going to release in dealloc method. I am new to objective C. Is this right way to avoid segmentation issues?.

```
-(void)dealloc{
  if(stringObject!=nil){
   [stringObject release];
   }
 }
```

Comment: if you are using ARC then there is no need to do this else you can directly release any object this will not create any issue

Comment: Thank you for all for your explanations. now i got clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing for `nil` before `release` is fully redundant in Objective C and will not add any resiliency to your code.

Indeed, the whole point of segmentation faults (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) is having a pointer **which is not nil**, thus points to some memory, and accessing that piece of memory after it has been freed.

If the pointer is nil in the first place you will not be possibly able to access any memory with it and you will not have a segmentation fault in Objective C (unlike C or C++).

The real solution to segmentation faults is correct memory management. If retain/release management seems too complex, you can have a look at ARC, which has its own intricacies, though (although much less than manual retain/release management).

Comment: true, but not relevant to the question

Comment: @Rob van der Veer: what is the question for you? for me it is: how to avoid segmentation faults... the OP clearly knows how to check for `nil`... the point is: is this useful to prevent segmentation faults? the answer is: NO.

Comment: i'm sorry, I'm learning that we all have different interpretations of what we read. Myself, i did not read anything about segmentation errors. Just the nil test. I think we can all come up with an example where an object-nil-test is handy. Nevertheless your explanation is good, we all learn.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: nevermind, multiple interpretations are the karma of the web. on the other hand, you are right, testing for nil is essential in all cases except when sending a message to an object.

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
if(stringObject)
```

will do, if you just want to check if the variable points to an object.

But with Objective C it is not necessary to test for `nil` because an message to a null object will simply do nothing. So it is enough to say:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [stringObject release];
    stringObject = nil;
    [super dealloc]; //added because of the comments
}
```

Under ARC, you can leave out the whole `dealloc` in most situations, because 1) the `release` is managed automatically, and 2) the call to dealloc is the made just before the object ends it's life, so the nil is not necessary. However, if you use custom c-style allocation you may still need an alloc method. But this belongs to an advanced topic.

Here's a link to the dev guide on working with objects in general:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1

Comment: You can *not* leave out dealloc if you're doing more in there than just releasing objects you've held. Granted, most of the time that's all that happened in dealloc, but as you're stating it, it's an oversimplification.

Comment: @PaulR, how does it not answer the question? "Can we check the object is nil or not before going to release in dealloc method.". Please explain

Comment: @PaulR As I read it, the question was, "what's the right way to safely release a maybe-nil object in Objective-C"; which this answers precisely and correctly.

Comment: @fzwo, if you are doing more than just releasing objects, use a different method like 'close' or 'cleanup' (viewWillDisappear?). The name `dealloc` should just do what it says: dealloc. Under ARC you should never have to see a [... dealloc] in your code.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer What would be your method of choice that gets called at the latest possible time in the lifetime of an object, if not dealloc? (except for the obvious logging you may sometimes want to put in there)

Comment: @RobvanderVeer @fzwo There are indeed valid uses for implementing `dealloc` under ARC. Some of the most obvious ones I've used it for is freeing C-style malloc'd buffers, releasing CoreFoundation types (although this is needed less in modern ARC), and closing file handles and sockets.

Comment: When you get to the point you need C-style malloc, you should be wise enough to use dealloc at your own preference. If you are beginning Objective C, such powers should be left alone.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: Sending `dealloc` is an error when compiling with ARC, and even under MRR the only proper use of `dealloc` is `[super dealloc]`, so it's not clear what you meant by "Under ARC you should never have to see a [... dealloc] in your code."

Comment: @JoshCaswell, Ok, i will add it. Although your comment should be to fzwo. Unless i'm mistake and you can write a dealloc under ARC, but not call it.

Comment: I was talking about [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759989/can-we-check-if-the-object-is-nil-or-not-before-going-to-release-in-dealloc-met/17760005?noredirect=1#comment25899213_17760005) which I quoted. And yes, it's exactly the case that you can write a `dealloc` method under ARC but not call it. (And as I said, you _shouldn't_ call it even under MRR. The only place `dealloc` should be sent from is `release`.)

Comment: We're on the same line now!

Comment: That dealloc implementation is incorrect under either ARC or MRR.

Comment: @bbum, at least tell us what's wrong... You're just bashing now, and more to the point, this thread is derailing from a question about an if statement to the use of dealloc.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer Under ARC, `retain` or `release` isn't allowed.  Under MRR, it doesn't call `[super dealloc]`.  Note that `if (aPointer)` does not test if `aPointer` points to an object; it tests if it is non-zero and nothing more.  I could do `id aPointer = (id) 0x123; if (aPointer) [aPointer hash];` and it'd crash.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @cobbal, I have no experience with MRRs thanks for covering my back with that crrection!

Answer (score 0):

This suffices as a nil test (your way is also correct, just slightly longer):

```
if (stringObject)
{
    //do something
}
```

But in a simple case like yours, you don't even have to do that, because in Objective-C, sending messages to nil objects just means nothing happens:

```
[aNilObject doSomething]; //nothing happens, this is perfectly valid and won't throw an exception; it won't even log anything. Once you're used to it, it's great and avoids lots of boilerplate nil checks.
```

Going further, in your case, you should switch to ARC (after you're done learning manual retain and release, which is a good exercise).

Your code would then look like this:

```
//you don't need to call dealloc at all in ARC :)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Before ARC there was a very common macro defined

`#define SAFE_RELEASE(object) if (object != nil) { [object release]; object = nil; }`

- NOTE: However, sending a message to nil will return nil.

Comment: Ugh, this smells. When would you ever have needed this? This is a sign that you simply did not balance your retains and releases properly. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @fzwo - I have never used this macro, I very well know how retain/release/autorelease works; but this was used in many projects (both open source and closed source) I have had to work with. Even Three20 was using it `#define TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil; }` So voting me down in this case "smells" badly. ;)

Comment: Just because you see it somewhere doesn't make it good practice. Especially not in three20.

Comment: Three20 was "widely" used by many at the very iOS 3.0 ages. Where I have said it was a good practice to use such macro? Where I've said Three20 was a great framework? I said "it was very common" macro. Go troll elsewhere.

Comment: As written, this macro will have a double-release problem. `object` will be released once in the release statement, then again in the `setObject:` property.

Comment: @cobbal - Yes in the hurry I put `object = nil;` outside the `if(){}`

Comment: @ludesign That's not what I meant. Assuming the setter (which gets called by `self.object = nil;`) is written (or synthesized) in the standard manner, it looks like `- (void) setObject:(id)newObject { [object release]; ... }` so object will get release called on it twice, even if you move the set to nil inside the `if` statement.

Comment: @ludesign Relax, I'm not downvoting you, I'm downvoting the answer you gave. It simply isn't helpful, it's harmful, regardless of whether it was widely used. I'll gladly lift the downvote if you can explain to me why this is a good practice. If you can't, why did you write it in an answer to an obvious beginner?

Comment: @cobbal - I saw the `self.` I put there, haha, stupid me. @fzwo - I just hate people telling me what is a good practice and what is not; as I have a head on my shoulders I can decide. To answer you: No it is not a good piece of code to use, being a macros or written as two lines of code (as in Rob van der Veer's answer). Masking dangling pointers might (and will) lead to unnoticed bugs and other consequences. The reason for this macros to exists is as kind of protection from dangling pointers in big projects with many contributors/developers. Keep the downvote, I do not care about SO points ;)

Comment: To finish this: I never said it was a good practice or suggested the OP to use it. Just verified what the OP asked and gave an example from old days. I respect your opinion; but please, don't put words in my mouth. Thanks. :)

Comment: This SAFE_RELEASE thing is nonsense, ignore it.